# Arrow characters are left behind on the screen

Tags: vimrc

Whenever I press and hold any arrow key (e.g. `h`, `j`, `k` or `l`) they appears on screen as such:

[image]

The same kind of thing happens whenever I accidentally scroll, where `^[OA` are displayed if I scroll up and `^[OB` displayed if I scroll down.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

OS: Debian 11

Vim version: 8.2

Ps: sorry if the tag is not relevant. I had to put one but have no idea as to which one to put in this case

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). Your problem look like a terminal specific problem. Do you have everything right after hitting `Ctrl-l` for redraw? Can you tell us what is your OS and your version of Vim?

Comment: You might also want to check the environment variable `TERM` (`:echo $TERM` in Vim) and the option `'term'` (`:set term?` in Vim)

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I'm running vim 8.2 on Debian 11. 
```Ctrl+l``` gets rid of all unwanted characters on screen (thanks!).
```:echo $TERM``` returns ```xterm-256color``` and ```:set term?``` returns ```term=xterm-256color```. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: In what terminal emulator?

Comment: the terminal emulator is konsole